# Changing the color of the whitespace indicator in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, whitespace, indicator

In Visual Studio we can show white space by **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**, **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>**.  But how can we change the color of the white space indicator itself?

[image]

I would like to change it to a soft gray so it the color is not as strong and not so distracting.

Comment: I've added a companion question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177374/changing-the-color-of-the-whitespace-specifically-for-comments-in-visual-studio to ask specifically what happens if you combine light and dark background at several tokens, as for example comments.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can do that in Tools / Options and then Environment / Fonts And Colors and there is a setting for visible White Space :

[image]

Comment: Sweet - never knew there were so many different things you can change the font for.

Comment: there is no tools there is no options, there is no environment. this answer is outdated.

Comment: @ahnbizcad VS 2019 has this like described, what VS version you are using ?

Comment: @ahnbizcad like antionio mentioned, it's still there. Just checked with my Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit)

Comment: How great - after 11 (!!) years this useful option is still at the same place and I found it quickly in the current version Visual Studio 2022 - even the dialog looks pretty much the same (-:

Comment: It took me 10 minutes to realize that the list is not sorted lexicographically. And it is not possible to search anything (the search in the options window will not find the elements in the list). So yeah, not sure if its good that it did not change in 11 years ;)

Answer (score 14):

I was searching on how to do the same on VS code and I ended up on that thread.
I found out that you can change it on the settings.json file. This one you can open if you go on Preferences/Settings and search for Color Customizations for the Workbench.

[image: vs code menu option for settings]

On the json file accordingly you will need to add (if it's not already there) the next property:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#1e6d9b"
    },
```

The color should be a hex code. In the example above I have "#1e6d9b" but feel free to replace it with your preference.

To customize for a specific theme only, use syntax like this, where `Monokai` is the name of the specific theme you want to override the value for:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
        "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#1e6d9b"
    }
}
```

Complete reference on customizing a color theme:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme
and theme color properties:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color